# How to retrieve the ngmodel value in the custom directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

All, I am trying to retrieve a ngmodel value when the button in a custom directive trigger the click event. But It seems the value is not ready in the link function. (Am I right ? Please correct me. ) How can I achieve it ?

Below is the html content in the directive template.

```
<div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" ng-disabled="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Input ICD10 code..." value="{{bindModel.ICDModel.DiseaseName}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="DrugDetailID" ng-model="bindModel.Detail.ID" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button  class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="button" ></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link function code looks like below:

```
lookupDir.link = function(scope, jqElement, attrs) {

    //var d =jqElement.find('[name="DrugDetailID"]').val();

    jqElement.find('button').bind('click', function() {
        debugger;
        var hdItem =jqElement.find('[name="DrugDetailID"]');
        var valItem =$(jqElement.find('[name="DrugDetailID"]')[0]).val();

        alert(valItem);//The value is always empty. I got nothing.
      });
  }
```

More detail please help to review the http://plnkr.co/edit/2la3BU8oaVjzyfFnKPJz?p=preview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value, you should be able to reference it with `scope.bindModel.Detail.ID`, unless I'm missing something?